# Formatting Active Record Timestamps for JSON API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rspec, datetime-format

I have a failing test for a GET request — the issue lies with the way ActiveRecord's timestamps are formatted in the response. The RSpec test expects the data format to be `Mon, 29 Dec 2014 13:37:09 UTC +00:00,`, but it instead receives `2014-12-29T13:37:09Z`. Is there any way to change the formatting of the ActiveRecord timestamp, or what the RSpec test expects?

**Edit:**

Here's the failing test:

```
describe 'GET /v1/tasks/:id' do 
  it 'returns an task by :id' do
    task = create(:task)
    get "/v1/tasks/#{task.id}"

    expect(response_json).to eq( 
      {
        'id' => task.id,
        'title' => task.title,
        'note' => task.note,
        'due_date' => task.due_date,
        'created_at' => task.created_at,
        'updated_at' => task.updated_at
      } 
    )
  end
end
```

The test fails on `created_at` and `updated_at`. `response_json` is a helper method that parses the JSON response.

Here's where the test fails:

```
   expected: {"id"=>1, "title"=>"MyString", "note"=>"MyText", "due_date"=>Mon, 29 Dec 2014, "created_at"=>Mon, 29 Dec 2014 13:37:09 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Mon, 29 Dec 2014 13:37:09 UTC +00:00}
        got: {"id"=>1, "title"=>"MyString", "note"=>"MyText", "due_date"=>"2014-12-29", "created_at"=>"2014-12-29T13:37:09Z", "updated_at"=>"2014-12-29T13:37:09Z"}
```

Comment: What is the specific RSpec line that is failing? Post it please.

Comment: @RichardAE Sorry about that! Just added that sample.

Comment: For future visitors: I solved the my question — it's at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was embarrassing simple — I had specify that the dates should be formatted using ISO 8601 using the `to_formatted_s()` method. Below is the correct, passing version:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'GET /v1/tasks/:id' do 
  it 'returns an task by :id' do
    task = create(:task)
    get "/v1/tasks/#{task.id}"

    expect(response_json).to eq( 
      {
        'id' => task.id,
        'title' => task.title,
        'note' => task.note,
        'due_date' => task.due_date.to_formatted_s(:iso8601),
        'created_at' => task.created_at.to_formatted_s(:iso8601),
        'updated_at' => task.updated_at.to_formatted_s(:iso8601)
      } 
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the date columns are being 'jsonified' in a format that you may or may not have specified. This value is of a different format and a string; therefore matching it with a date value fails.

To resolve this you could either adjust how the `created_at` value is 'jsonified' (format it) or you could just do this in your test:

```
columns = %w{id title note due_date created_at updated_at}

# get task as json string:
task_json_string = task.to_json(only: columns)

# turn json into hash
task_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(task_json_string) 

json_attributes = task_json.values.first

expected_hash = columns.each_with_object({}) do |attr, hash|
  # ensuring that the order of keys is as specified by 'columns'
  hash[attr] = json_attributes[attr]
end

expect(response_json).to eq expected_hash
```

That should work (minor debugging might be required though).

To go the former route, add an instance method like the following to your `Task` model:

```
def as_json( *args )
  super(*args).tap do |hash|
    attributes_hash = hash.values.first

    %w{created_at updated_at}.each do |attr|
      if attributes_hash.has_key?(attr)
        # Use strftime time instead of to_s to specify a format:
        attributes_hash[attr] = self.send(attr).to_s
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your test your `task` json could simply be:

```
task_json = task.as_json.values.first
```

Or after adding the `add_json` method and keeping the `to_s` there, in your test all you will need to do is add a `.to_s` to your date method e.g. `task.created_at.to_s`; the values will match.

Thereby removing the object-to-json-to-hash step and doing object-to-hash directly.

Answer (score 2):

The following Date and DateTime formatting should correct the problem.

```
{
  'id' => task.id,
  'title' => task.title,
  'note' => task.note,
  'due_date' => task.due_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z"),
  'created_at' =>task.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z"),
  'updated_at' =>task.updated_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
}
```

**EDIT**
Correction on date format.

Comment: It get me closer, but not quite there — it returns `2014-12-29T16:07:49Z`, instead of `2014-12-29 16:07:49 UTC`.

Answer (score 2):

As @Humza mentioned, the problem stems from how values are "jsonified".

**tl;dr** -- just change your spec to expect `'created_at' => task.created_at.as_json`

---

### The Long Version

In ActiveSupport (5.1.4), all values are run through `ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding#jsonify`:

```
def jsonify(value)
  case value
  when String
    EscapedString.new(value)
  when Numeric, NilClass, TrueClass, FalseClass
    value.as_json
  when Hash
    Hash[value.map { |k, v| [jsonify(k), jsonify(v)] }]
  when Array
    value.map { |v| jsonify(v) }
  else
    jsonify value.as_json
  end
end
```

As you can see, there's no special case for `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`, it just calls `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone#as_json`. So let's see what that looks like:

```
[1] pry(#<DataModelRowSerializer>)> show-source ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone#as_json

From: /Users/stevehull/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb @ line 165:
Owner: ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 7

def as_json(options = nil)
  if ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.use_standard_json_time_format
    xmlschema(ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.time_precision)
  else
    %(#{time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")} #{formatted_offset(false)})
  end
end
```

So if you wanted to, you could expect `'created_at' => task.created_at.xmlschema(ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.time_precision)`, however it's much more compact to use `as_json` ;)